# are atleast two premises a necessity for construction of a syllogism

Tags: logic

Wikipedia states that atleast 2 premises are required for a syllogism but the book http://14.139.206.50:8080/jspui/bitstream/1/2219/1/Gensler,%20Harry%20-%20Introduction%20to%20Logic.pdf gives examples of premiseless syllogisms for example; conclusion: All A is A.

Again if statement: No A is B & conclusion : No A is B. Will the conclusion follow? Also, irrespective of whether it follows or not, will it be a syllogism?

Comment: As you can see in Gensler, page 9, a *syllogism* is defined as "a vertical sequence of one or more wffs in which...". Thus (see example) "all $A$ is $A$" is a syllogism for Gensler. This is **not** the original [Aristotelian definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllogism) of *syllogism* (also called : [categorical syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllogism#Basic_structure)).

Comment: You have already received an answer in your previous post : [is-restatement-true-in-syllogism](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/41370/is-restatement-true-in-syllogism).

Comment: "Formally" we can reformulate them in Aristotelian form: "All $A$ is $A$, All $A$ is $A$; therefore All $A$ is $A$". And "No $A$ is $B$, AllL $B$ is $B$; therefore No $A$ is $B$. With clearly no benefit at all...

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on the meaning of 'syllogism'. Aristotle famously studied what are called categorical syllogisms that do indeed always require exactly two premises. Moreover, the two premises and the conclusion are all Categorical sentences of the type (some/all) P's (are/are not) Q's, and finally, the two premises and the conclusion together talk about 3 different categories ... Which is why Venn diagrams are a great way to analyze such categorical syllogisms.

Anyway, the point is, historically, syllogisms were understood to be a very specific pattern of argument that indeed always involved exactly two premises.  But nowadays, you may find people use the word 'syllogism' much more loosely, and indeed pretty much any pattern of argument can be called some kind of 'syllogism'. As such, you can indeed have syllogisms with 1, or 3, or even no premises at all.

Oh, and

> No A is B
>
> $\therefore$ No A is B

is of course valid (did you maybe mean to conclude No B is A?  That would be a bit more interesting, and yes, that would be valid as well.)

Is it a syllogism? Well, it is not a classical syllogism, but with today's more loose use of the word, I am sure someone could come up with some interesting name 'blah blah Syllogism' for this pattern.